# Python get client windows user from intranet

Tags: python, ldap, tornado

Basically i'm looking for an alternative of https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm for Python/Tornado

I could just add node.js as another layer in the application but I'd rather not

A way to get the windows user of the client acessing a url

This will be used in a web app only available on a corporate network

Comment: What are you deploying on? Apache/NGINX/IIS/etc?

Comment: @sytech IIS is what we have setup for now, but I'm open to any suggestion

Comment: You can get this information from the IIS environment variables. I will supply an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

When deploying on IIS with IIS handling Windows authentication, you can retrieve the remote user from the environment variables. This assumes you have [Windows authentication](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication) enabled and configured.

Then you can simply get the variables out of the environment. As noted in the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx) applicable environment variables include `REMOTE_USER`, `AUTH_USER`, `LOGON_USER`, and `UNMAPPED_REMOTE_USER`. Check the docs for specific usages.

In Python, these can be retrieved with `os.environ`
Tested this using IIS 7.5 running a simple script and was able to get the username with Python simply by `os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER")`

If you're using a proxy, the environment variable may be different, such as `'HTTP_X_PROXY_REMOTE_USER'`. The server may also need to be configured to pass those environment variables along if that's the case.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me, the documentation says they are server variable, not enviroment variables. It doesn't even appear if I print os.environ

Comment: @Mojimi It's likely necessary that IIS be configured to pass these variables down into the application (WSGI) environment in the app settings. Further, if a proxy is used, the variables may need to be explicitly allowed as well. If using `wfastcgi.py`, you can also try using `os.getenv` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`express-ntlm` is based on an Apache Python project that does the very same: https://github.com/Legrandin/PyAuthenNTLM2/